# How to shift values in tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I have tensor T of shape [batch_size, A] with values and tensor S of shape [batch_size] with shift parameters.

I would like to shift values in T[b] by S[b] positions to the right, the last S[b] elements of T[b] should be dropped and new elements should be set to 0.

So basically want to do something like:

```
for i in range(batch_size):
  T[i] = zeros[:S[i]] + T[i, :A-S[i]]
```

Example:

```
For:
T = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
S = [1, 2]

Return:
T' = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 0, 4]]
```

Is there some easy way to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to roll without periodic boundaries in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54782144/how-to-roll-without-periodic-boundaries-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 1):

using `tf.reverse()`, `tf.reverse_sequence()`, and applying a mask using `tf.sequence_mask()`.

first way:

```py
T = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
S = tf.constant([1, 2])
#expected_out T' = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 0, 4]]

t = tf.reverse_sequence(T, [2,1], seq_axis=1, batch_axis=0)
#[[2, 1, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

t = tf.reverse(t,[1])
#[[3, 1, 2], [6, 5, 4]]

mask = tf.sequence_mask([1,2],3)
t*tf.cast(~mask,"int32")
#[[0, 1, 2], [0, 0, 4]] ##
```

`tf.reverse_sequence()` will select from each axis number of elements, and then reverse them. here we choose to reverse first two elements in the first array and first element in the second array. Then we reversed the whole sequence because we want the first elements to be move to the end of the Tensor. that shows the importance of the first reverse, because in the second reverse they will return to their original order. then we applied the mask to make the first unwanted elements = 0.
this method is flexible you can choose the amount you want to shift left your sequence for each elemnet and associate it with the mask in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tf.concat and tf.stack for that purpose:

```
T_shift = tf.zeros((batch_size, A), tf.float32)
tmp = []

for i in xrange(batch_size):
    tmp.append(tf.concat([T_shift[i, :S[i, 0]],T[i, :17 - S[i,0]]], axis = 0))
T_shift = tf.stack(tmp)
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are working in Tensorflow 2, you can use the [tf.roll](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/roll) for that purpose:

> "The elements are shifted positively (towards larger indices) by the
>   offset of shift along the dimension of axis. Negative shift values
>   will shift elements in the opposite direction. Elements that roll
>   passed the last position will wrap around to the first and vice versa.
>   Multiple shifts along multiple axes may be specified."

```
tf.roll(
       input, shift, axis, name=None
)

# 't' is [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
roll(t, shift=2, axis=0) ==> [3, 4, 0, 1, 2]

# shifting along multiple dimensions
# 't' is [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
roll(t, shift=[1, -2], axis=[0, 1]) ==> [[7, 8, 9, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 0, 1]]

# shifting along the same axis multiple times
# 't' is [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
roll(t, shift=[2, -3], axis=[1, 1]) ==> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 0], [6, 7, 8, 9, 5]]
```

Comment: The op states that "new elements should be set to 0", `tf.roll()` wraps around, instead of setting new elements to 0.