# How to roll without periodic boundaries in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need a transformation of a tensor which is very similar to roll. The difference is that I do not want the values from the end of the axis to appear in the beginning. In other words I want, for example, the 2nd element to be on 3d place but I do not want the last element to become the first one. Instead, I want the first elements to be zeros.

I have tried this:

```
prev_xs = tf.roll(xs, shift = 1, axis = 1)
prev_xs[:,0] = 0.0
```

However, it does not work because

```
TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment
```

So, what is the proper solution of the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use

```
prev_xs = tf.concat((tf.zeros([tf.shape(xs)[0], 1]), xs[:, :1]), axis=1)
```

Step-by-step, we discard the last column of `xs` by indexing like `[:, :1]`. We create a column of zeros with the appropriate number of rows. Then we concatenate it in front of `xs`, pushing every column back by 1.